# A quick question on transcendence

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've seen the following claim in my notes, but I couldn't see why it's true:
Suppose that $y \in F_p((x))$ is transcendent over $F_p(x)$, denote $L:=F_p(x, y)$ and let $L^p$ be the field of $p$th powers of $L$.

My question is:

> Why is $[L : L^p]=p^2$?

Comment: That $y$ is taken in $\mathbf{F}_p((x))$ seems like a strange detail.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints; if you like, I'll say more. If you can show that $[L : L^p(x)]$ and $[L^p(x) : L^p]$ are both $p$, then the [tower law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees) gives you the degree of $L$ over $L^p$, and the standard proof of that law shows that maxymoo gave you a basis.

I think the interesting step is showing that if $k$ is a field of characteristic $p > 0$, and $t$ is transcendental over $k$, then $[k(t) : k(t^p)] = p$. Clearly $t$ satisfies the polynomial $f(X) = X^p - t^p$ over $k(t^p)$, so we must show that $f$ is irreducible. As $f(X) = (X - t)^p$ in the larger field, if we have a non-trivial factor of $f$ over $k(t^p)$ then it is [associate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_element#Divisibility.2C_prime_and_irreducible_elements) to $(X - t)^r$ for some $1 \leqq r < p$. Assuming we have such a factor, show that $t \in k(t^p)$.

Thus it is enough to show that $t$ is not in $k(t^p)$. If it were, then we'd have $g(X), h(X) \in k[X]$ satisfying
$$
t = \frac{g(t^p)}{h(t^p)}.
$$
Why is this impossible?

Fun corollary: $L$ is not a [simple extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension) of $L^p$.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure i misunderstand the question, but is it because you can take $\{x^iy^j\}_{0\leqslant i,j \leqslant p-1}$ as your $L^p$-basis of $L$?

Comment: Can you please explain further why this is indeed a basis?